# my procedure compiled but i am not getting any output

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TOTAL_INCOME(i_hotel_ID IN NUMBER) IS
   l_total NUMBER(10);     
BEGIN    
   SELECT SUM((1 - (BOOKING_DISCOUNT/100.0))*(SRV_RESTAURANT + SRV_PPV + SRV_LAUNDRY)) 
     INTO l_total 
     FROM invoice 
    WHERE hotel_id = i_hotel_ID; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Income : ' ||l_total);    
END;
/
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the procedure? Or are you expecting the output while compiling?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the procedure with an ID value as a parameter such as

```
DECLARE
  v_hotel_ID invoice.hotel_id%type := 251;
BEGIN
  TOTAL_INCOME(v_hotel_ID);
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=137cc14310bd6ba969314fb5d30c1d5b)</kbd>